# Why won't my new powerstroke 5kW generator start?

Tags: generator

I purchased a power stroke 5,000 watt generator about a year ago. Only recently there have been some power issues in my area, which made me decide to take it out and get it ready. I purchased new gas & oil, but it would not start. I tried spraying gas in the carb, and still nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you ensured you are following the proper startup procedure from the manual? i.e. no lock-out key, choke, etc.  does it sound like its turning over at all?  is there resistance on the starter cord, or is it an electric start?

Comment: Yes, I read the manual first. Then I set it it up which was very simple. I even watched a few you tube videos on it.

Comment: Is there a fuel shutoff valve that's still closed?

Comment: Did you follow the 1+ year storage instructions last year? If not, fuel may have gummed and clogged the carburetor, you might need to clean it. If you did follow their instructions (which includes removing the spark plug and squirting some oil in the cylinder), did you remember to reconnect the spark plug wire after you replaced the spark plug?

Comment: There is no fuel shut off valve. I never followed any storage instructions since I never took it from the box until right now. It has been closed and in the box since the day it was delivered. I know that the spark plug should be wet, and it is not....

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I didn't understand that it was brand new still in box. Maybe it's DOA from the manufacturer - $600 5000W generators don't earn their low price by using the highest quality components and manufacturing. Looks like it may have a 2 year warranty, so a trip back to the store might be in order. Did you double check the oil level to be sure the low-oil sensor isn't preventing it from starting? Is it on level ground? Did you try with and without using the choke?

Answer (score 2):

Most engines don't like to start after extended storage. One cause is a dry cylinder bore which prevents compression.

Solution: pull the spark plug and squirt a generous amount of oil into the cylinder. Like 25% of displacement. Turn the generator so the cylinder is vertical and leave it for a few hours so the oil can flow into the piston grooves. Return it to upright for 30 minutes (so fluids can drain to the proper position).

**Very important**: Cover the spark plug hole with paper towel and crank for 5-10 seconds. A considerable amount of oil should blow out of the plug hole. Now replace the plug and try starting again.

Comment: Crank over by hand, electric start with too much oil in the cylinder can hydraulic lock the piston, bend ring lands and fracture aluminum connecting rods.

Comment: @FiascoLabs That's what the paper towel over the plug hole is for. And also why the sentence begins with "very important"

Answer (score 0):

Three things are required: spark, fuel, and compression.

Some generators have a low oil pressure cut off switch. check if the wires are on it. Check it for continuity with a meter.  Look again for a stop/run switch.

I have never seen a generator without a fuel shutoff valve, so carefully check again. You could also take the fuel line off the carburetor and see if gas is making it that fare.

Compression: does it take force to pull the starter rope, or is it electric start? If electric, do you hear the compression strokes. Or does it sound the same as if the spark plug was out.

There are some shade-tree ways for checking for spark that I'm sure you can find on the internet. Don't want to mention here because I will get negative reps for suggesting something dangerous.

Comment: And oxygen. The [fire triangle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_triangle) says that oxygen is important in making fire. Check for rodent nests in the air filter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pull cord. Does cord pull or just stop stuck? If stuck, then pistons or cord are jammed.
2. Disconnect spark plug. Pull cord. Does spark appear? If no spark appears, problem is electrical.
3. Only thing left is fuel. Cylinders could be flooded, or carburetor is not working or fuel line is blocked. Clean everything.